# Loop through a list and find the 2nd element of each member in R

Tags: r, statistics

I want to go through a list and get the second element of each list member.

Is there a better (more efficient/elegant/both) way to do it than the following?

```
lapply(ee,function(x){return(x[2])})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the subsetting function `[` as the argument to `lapply`

```
ee <- list(x=cars[,1], y=cars[,2])
lapply(ee, `[`, 2)
$x
[1] 4

$y
[1] 10
```